# Return if a given int is an exponent of 2 C#

Tags: c#

Given a method of the bool data type that takes in an int variable, what is a **single** line of code that would determine if the int is an exponent of 2 or 2^n.....2,4,8,16,32 etc. I know of a way using a while loop and if statements, but I'm looking for it to be on one line.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#DetermineIfPowerOf2):

```
uint v;         // we want to see if v is a power of 2
bool f;         // the result goes here 

f = (v != 0) && ((v & (v - 1)) == 0);
```

Comment: Works for uint, but for an int variable, you need to exclude 0x80000000

Comment: So, change the check for v != 0 to v > 0, then you're set to go.

Answer (score 6):

Just check if the log (base 2) of the number is an integer.

In one line of C#:

```
Math.Log(x, 2) % 1 == 0
```

Bitwise operations are more fun, but lord have mercy on whomever has to maintain that code.

Comment: What about for example 25? The square root is 5 (an integer) but not a valid number in this case.

Comment: It's downvoted because I originally misread the question and posted an incorrect answer. It has since been edited to a correct solution.

Comment: @Tom and why do we care about the square root? This is logarithms.

Answer (score 4):

```
bool powerOfTwo = (unchecked(n & (n-1)) == 0) && (n != 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
bool answer = ((n & ~(n-1)) == n && n!=0);
```

This passes all the basic tests I threw at it.

It seems good.